# read.table with defined number of columns in R

Tags: r, read.table

Suppose I have a raw text file, f.txt, such like this:

```
100040390   mmu04120:Ubiquitin mediated proteolysis
100040390   mmu05020:Parkinson's disease
100163  mmu00565:Ether lipid metabolism
```

If I do `read.table(f.txt)` it will automatically sep by tab/white space:

```
    V1               V2                V3         V4
1 100040390   mmu04120:Ubiquitin     mediated proteolysis                     
2 100040390 mmu05020:Parkinson's      disease                                 
3    100163       mmu00565:Ether        lipid  metabolism
```

My question is how to read it into r with 2 columns such like:

```
    V1               V2              
1 100040390   mmu04120:Ubiquitin mediated proteolysis                     
2 100040390   mmu05020:Parkinson's disease                                 
3    100163   mmu00565:Ether lipid metabolism
```

Comment: Maybe `read.csv(text = gsub("\\s{2,}", ",", readLines(txt)), header = FALSE)` would do it.  Works for me on the example.

Comment: `fread(txt, header=F, sep="\t")` works pretty well too. But both solutions depend on the variety of examples in your data.

Comment: Are your columns tab delimited or not? You can use `sep="\t"` with `read.table` if they are. (And probably `quote=""`)

Comment: @MrFlick couldn't get that to work. Richard, I just saw that. Maybe read in as is and split after.

Comment: Thanks, I tried first one but I just got one column @RichardScriven. needs to add sep="\t". It works now.

Comment: That file format should be tab separated. So, use `sep = '\t'`.